# несколько анимаций на одном объекте unity3d

Tags: unity3d

подскажите, каким образом можно добавить на один объект несколько анимаций, чтоб можно было их менять между собой (см. рисунок), проигрывать и добавлять события? а то на события пишет "AnimationEvent has no receiver! Are you missing a component?". На самом объекте все есть: скрипт с функциями-событиями, компоненты Animation со списком анимаций и Animator с контроллером. в выделенной области должен выпадать список со всеми анимациями на объекте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
модель со всеми анимациями импортил из blender'a в формате fbx. все анимации работают (в окне инспектора проигрывается как надо)

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать [AnimatorController](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html) - asset, в котором и будут заданы все эти переходы между состояниями. А сам он должен быть помещён в Animator - компонент, который должен находиться на анимируемом объекте.

Comment: Ссылка битая - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, о как, спасибо. Я её просто скопировал из адресной строки о.о

Comment: В последнее время доки у юнити постоянно такие фокусы выделывают, видимо, связано с релизом новых фич и доков к ним.

Comment: все есть. и Animator с прикрепленным контроллером и условия перехода анимаций в самом аниматоре. и к тому же разве от них зависит, что в окне Animation нет списка?

Comment: @Zero, вы выбрали объект, на котором висит аниматор или просто анимацию выбрали в файлах? Список будет только в первом случае

Comment: да, сам объект с аниматором